# Binary Bomb [Phase 5]

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

This is the 5th phase of the bomb lab, I have been stuck on it for a couple of days. I know this takes in a string of length 6.I also know that the input has to be added up to be 74[0x4a]. I am confused on what needs to be done

I used the input string:-
10 12 16 7 14 15 (Sum of 74)
And indexed it 1  4  5  9 10 14

And I came to the input - iadpde
But still it's not working.
Can someone guide me for the same, What am I doing wrong?The code is below.

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
=> 0x0000555555555488 <+0>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000555555555489 <+1>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x000055555555548c <+4>:     callq  0x555555555709 <string_length>
   0x0000555555555491 <+9>:     cmp    $0x6,%eax
   0x0000555555555494 <+12>:    jne    0x5555555554c7 <phase_5+63>
   0x0000555555555496 <+14>:    mov    %rbx,%rax
   0x0000555555555499 <+17>:    lea    0x6(%rbx),%rdi
   0x000055555555549d <+21>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x00005555555554a2 <+26>:    lea    0x15f7(%rip),%rsi        # 0x555555556aa0 <array.3416>
   0x00005555555554a9 <+33>:    movzbl (%rax),%edx
   0x00005555555554ac <+36>:    and    $0xf,%edx
   0x00005555555554af <+39>:    add    (%rsi,%rdx,4),%ecx
   0x00005555555554b2 <+42>:    add    $0x1,%rax
   0x00005555555554b6 <+46>:    cmp    %rdi,%rax
   0x00005555555554b9 <+49>:    jne    0x5555555554a9 <phase_5+33>
   0x00005555555554bb <+51>:    cmp    $0x4a,%ecx
   0x00005555555554be <+54>:    je     0x5555555554c5 <phase_5+61>
   0x00005555555554c0 <+56>:    callq  0x555555555a1f <explode_bomb>
   0x00005555555554c5 <+61>:    pop    %rbx
   0x00005555555554c6 <+62>:    retq
   0x00005555555554c7 <+63>:    callq  0x555555555a1f <explode_bomb>
   0x00005555555554cc <+68>:    jmp    0x555555555496 <phase_5+14>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) x/16 0x555555556aa0
0x555555556aa0 <array.3416>:    2       10      6       1
0x555555556ab0 <array.3416+16>: 12      16      9       3
0x555555556ac0 <array.3416+32>: 4       7       14      5
0x555555556ad0 <array.3416+48>: 11      8       15      13
```

Comment: How did you get the input from the indices? For example ascii code of `i` is `0x69` which clearly does not end in `1` that you need.

Comment: i thought we could use 69 as it ends in 9

Comment: It does end in `9` but why do you need a `9`? You need a `1`. You said yourself: _"indexed it 1 4 5 9 10 14"_

Comment: beacuse i cant use the ascii of 0x1 = SOH

Comment: sorry i posted the wrong input , i tried that and many others as well

Comment: `9` is not `1`. Pick something that ends in `1`. Does not need to be `0x01`. Could be `0x61`=`a`.

Comment: i tried ),-126 as input , is stilll not working

Comment: Well at least the `)` is correct. The rest of them make no sense. `,` is `0x2C` that does not end in `4`.

Comment: why? can u suggest an input?

Comment: For example, `1459jn` (as the decimal digits trivially identity map)

Comment: ohhh man, i feel so dumb right now

Comment: Thanks a lot couldn't have done it without u

Comment: You have put in more effort than the usual bomb squad people who come asking :)